# How to load limited data every time from realtime database in android kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `limitToFirst()` to load limited data every time user reaches last item. This is my code:-

```
val typesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Types")
typesRef.limitToFirst(5).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            typesAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            val Type = snapshot.getValue(Type_Model::class.java)
            if (Type != null) {
                (type as ArrayList<SU_Type_Model>).add(Type)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

    }
})
```

I don't know how to do this. I tried to refer other questions but I got only `limitToFirst()` as the solution but it is not working for me.

I don't know how to use notifyitemchanged(). Can you tell me how to use it?

here is database structure:-

```
{
    "Types": {
    "fasfd": {
    "ImageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehsdafi-10.appspot.com/o/Types%2FAR%20VR(Augmented%20%2B%20Virtual%20Reality)%2FAR%20VR(Augmented%20%2B%20Virtual%20Reality).jpg?alt=media&token=be4e930d-385c-4c2f-a4f4-b78bceafae",
    "type": "fasfd"
},
    "asfas": {
    "ImageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehsdafi-10.appspot.com/o/Types%2FAdvertising%2FAdvertising.jpg?alt=media&token=0dfac784-9824-4e12-8718-daf02ae5b36a",
    "type": "asfas"
},
    "kghjgh": {
    "ImageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehsdafi-10.appspot.com/o/Types%2FAeronautics%20Aerospace%20%26%20Defence%2FAeronautics%20Aerospace%20%26%20Defence.jpg?alt=media&token=b6731eb9-dc3a-4970-983b-011fba465152",
    "type": "kghjgh"
},
    "ityutyu": {
    "ImageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehsdafi-10.appspot.com/o/Types%2FAgriculture%2FAgriculture.jpg?alt=media&token=2ae737f4-c919-40e5-bceb-01812f702f59",
    "type": "ityutyu"
},
    "dfgdafg": {
    "ImageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehsdafi-10.appspot.com/o/Types%2FAirport%20Operations%2FAirport%20Operations.jpg?alt=media&token=d30a0581-c6d5-4416-960b-0b137227b952",
    "type": "dfgdafg"
},
    "bvnvbn": {
    "ImageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehsdafi-10.appspot.com/o/Types%2FAnalytics%2FAnalytics.jpg?alt=media&token=8ea94ab8-5625-4dbc-a7bd-2dea62823aeb",
    "type": "bvnvbn"
},
    "gfhdfgh": {
    "ImageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehsdafi-10.appspot.com/o/Types%2FAnimation%2FAnimation.jpg?alt=media&token=3d20e288-0833-4860-94fe-3a86895842fc",
    "type": "gfhdfgh"
}
}
}
```

Here is the model code:-

```
class Type_Model {

    private var ImageUrl: String = ""
    private var type: String = ""

    constructor()

    constructor(
        ImageUrl: String,
        type: String
    ) {
        this.ImageUrl = ImageUrl
        this.type = type
    }


    fun getImageUrl(): String {
        return ImageUrl
    }

    fun gettype(): String {
        return type
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: I am not getting any error. But it is loading only first 5 items in the list. If I remove the limit it loads all the data.

Comment: That's the expected behavior since your calling `.limitToFirst(5)`, right? Have also tried to move `typesAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()` right before the if statement ends?

Comment: I tried keeping `typesAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()` everywhere in the `onDataChange()` function. But it is not working.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have added the database structure.

Comment: Please also edit your question and add the content of your `Type_Model` class.

Comment: I have added model code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you have different names for the fields in the class than the ones in the database. The minimum declaration of the class should be:

```
data class Type_Model(
    @get:PropertyName("ImageUrl")
    @set:PropertyName("ImageUrl")
    @PropertyName("ImageUrl")
    var imageUrl: String? = null,
    var type: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to use `notifyitemchanged()` instead of notifyDataSetChanged() in this example as the position is required in  `notifyitemchanged(). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That has to be used on the adapter object, and not inside de model class. If you have a hard time implementing  that, please post a new question here on Stackoverflow so I and other Firebase developers can take a look.